# Convert List<byte[]> to one byte[] array

Tags: c#, .net

How do I convert `List<byte[]>` in one `byte[]` array, or one `Stream`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) should do the trick:

```
var listOfArrays = new List<byte[]>();

byte[] array = listOfArrays
                .SelectMany(a => a)
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 for being the only one to notice the OP has a List<byte[]> rather than List<byte>

Answer (score 7):

```
var myList = new List<byte>();
var myArray = myList.ToArray();
```

EDIT: OK, turns out the question was actually about `List<byte[]>` - in which case you need to use SelectMany to flatten a sequence of sequences into a single sequence.

```
var listOfArrays = new List<byte[]>();
var flattenedList = listOfArrays.SelectMany(bytes => bytes);
var byteArray = flattenedList.ToArray();
```

Docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx

Comment: *(reference)* [List<T>.ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx)

Comment: The OP have fixed her/his question, we're talking about `List<byte[]>`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [List<T>.ToArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: No, but perhaps because the OP have fixed her/his question. We're talking about `List<byte[]>`.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a little sloppy, could use some optimizing, but you get the gist of it

```
var buffers = new List<byte[]>();    
int totalLength = buffers.Sum<byte[]>( buffer => buffer.Length );    
byte[] fullBuffer = new byte[totalLength];

int insertPosition = 0;
foreach( byte[] buffer in buffers )
{
    buffer.CopyTo( fullBuffer, insertPosition );
    insertPosition += buffer.Length;
}
```

Comment: This is probably more efficient than Peter Lillevold answer (though I haven't tested)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the actual class `System.Collections.Generic.List<byte>`, call ToArray(). It returns a new `byte[]`.