# 'List(Of Byte())' to 'Byte()' in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of bytes:

```
Public Function GenPackets()
    Dim Stream As NetworkStream = ConnectionSocket.GetStream()
    Dim DataList As New List(Of Byte())
    Dim Data As Byte()
    DataList.Add(IntegerToByte(My.Settings.BotUID))

    ' TO DO       Stream.Write(Data, 0, 3)
    Return Data
End Function
```

How can I convert `DataList` and all of its bytes to a single Byte() for use in `Stream.Write`?

Comment: That seems the wrong approach. If you need this for `Stream.Write` then why not iterate over the list and write each byte array individually?

Comment: Konrad's answer is correct that you don't need to convert it to a single byte array if you want to write to a stream. But, for anyone who comes across this question to find out how to create a single byte array, you can use LINQ's `SelectMany` to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868113/convert-listbyte-to-one-byte-array

Comment: @keyboardP would you please show me how to use SelectMany in vb.net ?

Comment: @Shahriyar -  Dim dataArray As Byte() = DataList.SelectMany(Function(a) a).ToArray()

Comment: What do you mean a single byte?  Byte is limited to 255 bits.  Its very likely BotUID can be larger then 255.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Konrad Rudolph already wrote, you don't need to flatten the data in order to write it to your stream.

For the sake of completeness, you can flatten your data list like this

```
Dim dataList As New List(Of Byte())
Dim data As Byte()

data = dataList.SelectMany(Function(x) x).ToArray()
```

Or with the LINQ syntax

```
data = (From bytes In dataList From x In bytes Select x).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 7):

No need to convert your data, just iterate over the list:

```
For Each buffer As Byte() In Datalist
    yourStream.Write(buffer)
Next
```

This is vastly more efficient than first concatenating all the individual arrays to create one big array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not looking for this,This will send multiple packets to server,I want to Join all bytes in Byte List and send them in a single packet

Comment: @Shahriyar I think you misunderstand how packets work. Packets are created on a much lower layer. One call to `Write` does *not* correspond to one packet. Writes are buffered and sent in packets depending on *size*. In fact, if you’re using a `NetworkStream` then each byte will be written individually by the [`WriteByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.writebyte.aspx) method no matter what.

Comment: … unless you set the underlying socket’s buffer size to 0. But [the default is 8192 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendbuffersize.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could do the `List` of Bytes instead of arrays:

```
Dim DataList As New List(Of Byte)
DataList.AddRange(IntegerToByte(My.Settings.BotUID))

Data = DataList.ToArray()
```